# Adding datatables/dataframes in an excel(to different sheets) dynamically in R

Tags: r, data.table

Please let me know if there are any methods in R to add Datatables/Dataframes to different sheets in a single excel dynamically based on their availability.

Eg : Assume there are three Datatables DF1 , DF2 ,DF3 out of which DF1 will be available without any conditions ,but DF2 and DF3 are to be stored dynamically only if they exist, i.e. if their conditions are satisfied based on the variables of c and d that are passed.

```
a = c(1,2,3,4,5)
b = c(6,7,8,9,10)
c = 5
d = 10

df1 = data.table(a,b)
if(c > d){
  df2 = data.table(a)
}
if(d > c){
  df3 = data.table(b)
}
```

I need to store DF1 and DF2 and/or DF3(based on their availability) on a single excel file in different sheets.

Comment: you could use [openxlsx::AddWorksheet](https://rdrr.io/cran/openxlsx/man/addWorksheet.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
library(openxlsx)
mywb <- createWorkbook("Fred")
found <- Filter(exists, c("df1", "df2", "df3"))
for (nm in found) {
  addWorksheet(mywb, nm)
  writeData(mywb, sheet = nm, get(nm))
}
saveWorkbook(mywb, "myworkbook.xlsx")
```